# Laravel request URI not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-request, laravel-blade

I have the following route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

     // some more routes...
});
```

In my layout file I have the following condition:

```
 @if (Request::is('admin/*'))
            @include('layouts.partials.admin_header')
 @else
            @include('layouts.partials.header')
 @endif
```

When I navigate to `www.examplesite.com/admin/` it's not displaying in the admin header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you have in browser `www.examplesite.com/admin/` Laravel will see url is `admin` so `admin/*` pattern will not match in this case because there won't be slash in url. To fix this it seems you should use:

```
@if (Request::is('admin','admin/*'))
```

instead of

```
@if (Request::is('admin/*'))
```

in your Blade file.

Now both `/admin/` and `/admin/whatever` should work and you should get for both of them admin header